# Ruby Index and Show views are showing no data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby, and I'm developing my own app in Nitrous.

When I complete a form on my new.html.erb, and hit save, the show view loads.  The page renders with HTML headers as expected, but no data fields from my model.  I have also tried the index view, but there is no data being saved, I think.

I have generated a model called income, and run rake db:migrate successfully, wiht the right tables set up. I'm stumped as to what the problem is.

Any ideas gratefully received.

This is my controller: incomes_controller.rb

```
class IncomesController < ApplicationController 

  def index
  @incomes = Income.all
end

def new
  @income = Income.new
end

def create
 @income = Income.new(income_params)
 if @income.save
  redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @income.id)
 end
end

def show
 @income = Income.find(params[:id])
end


private

def income_params
 params.require(:income).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :income1, :income2, :income3, :income4, :income5, :income6, :income7, :income8, :income9, :income10)
 end
end
```

My form in new.html.erb, is:

```
<%= simple_form_for @income do |f| %>  
    <%= f.input :first_name, label: 'First Name' %> 
    <%= f.input :last_name, label: 'Last Name' %> 
    <%= f.input :date_of_birth, label: 'Date of Birth', hint: 'dd/mm/yyyy' %> 

<p>Income: Salary or Wages</p>
<%= f.input  :income1, label: 'Take home salary or Wage' %>
<%= f.input  :income2, label: 'Partner\'s salary or wage' %>
<%= f.input  :income3, label: 'Other income from salary or wages' %>

<p>Other Income</p>
<%= f.input  :income4, label: 'Maintanence or child support' %>
<%= f.input  :income5, label: 'Boarders or lodgers' %>
<%= f.input  :income6, label: 'Non-dependent contributions' %>
<%= f.input  :income7, label: 'Student loands or grants' %>
<%= f.input  :income7, label: 'Other' %>

<p>Benefits </p>
<%= f.input  :income8, label: 'Sample input' %>
<%= f.input  :income9, label: 'Sample input' %>
<%= f.input  :income10, label: 'More sample inputs' %>

<%= f.button :submit, "Save and Proceed" %>
<h3>You will have a chance to review your form before you submit it.  Once you click Save, you can come back and complete the rest of the form at a later date</h3>

<% end %>
```

And my show.html.erb file is:

```
<p>
  <strong>First name:</strong>
  <%= @income.first_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Last name:</strong>  
  <%= @income.last_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Date of Birth:</strong>  
  <%= @income.date_of_birth %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Take home salary or Wage:</strong>  
  <%= @income.income1 %>
</p>
```

My model income.rb is:

```
class Income < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :income1, :income2, :income3, :income4, :income5, :income6, :income7, :income8, :income9, :income10 
end
```

**Development log output....**

Processing by IncomesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"D4F40TAMcVsb7RbdUZwxXfsgGn1u/iD7R+DWvAwrtJ1q83mgequQbkyKPaheFjsLSZHlMBpDy+H7Rm+HdVeTFw==", "income"=>{"first_name"=>"Barak", "last_name"=>"Obama", "date_of_birth"=>"02/07/1990", "income1"=>"12345", "income2"=>"12345", "income3"=>"", "income4"=>"", "income5"=>"", "income6"=>"", "income7"=>"", "income8"=>"", "income9"=>"", "income10"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save and Proceed"}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "incomes" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", "2015-02-19 17:39:54.471034"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-19 17:39:54.471034"]]
  [1m[35m (32.8ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://o-bot-laboratory-190030.euw1.nitrousbox.com/incomes/42

Started GET "/incomes/42" for 88.215.13.57 at 2015-02-19 17:39:54 +0000
Processing by IncomesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"42"}
  [1m[36mIncome Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "incomes".* FROM "incomes" WHERE "incomes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 42]]
  Rendered incomes/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 75.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

Routes as requested....

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :incomes
 root 'incomes#new' 
end
```

Comment: `redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @income.id)` replace this line in create by this line and try `redirect_to @post, notice: 'Income was successfully created.'` and in show page just print `@income` value

Comment: Thanks.  I received the error after hitting save: "ActionController::ActionControllerError in IncomesController#create  Cannot redirect to nil!"  Thoughts?

Comment: Is your income saved into database?

Comment: `redirect_to @income, notice: 'Income was successfully created.'` is giving this error, means prbm with @income, check the value of @income `@income = Income.new(income_params)` after this statement

Comment: @ jyrkim, sorry I have to play dumb here, I'm a newbie. ..How can I find out if the income is in the database?  Looking at the developer log, I would have assumed yes.

Comment: What version of rails are you using? If 4 then you don't need this line attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :income1, :income2, :income3, :income4, :income5, :income6, :income7, :income8, :income9, :income10

Comment: No worries :-) I've been there too. Also I'm relative new with rails as well :-) But I'd try sth like in this Rails tutorial code: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb   I mean try using if else block. (ignore flash)

Comment: @RailsOuter , Rails 4.  I tried, no dice:  "undefined method `first_name' for #<Income id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>"

Comment: okay, yep you probably have to update your Income Controller to use Strong parameters http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html and from your Income model remove your attr_accessor line of code.

Comment: @jyrkim I can confirmed it saves.  I used your if /else.   Still no data showing though.   I will try your next bit of advice now.

Comment: Sorry I noticed that you probably just need to remove: attr_accessor line of code from your Income model. Your controller is already Rails 4 compatible.  So I think your Model is Rails 3 compatible (that might be the issue here) and Controller Rails 4 compatible.

Comment: As far as I can tell my strong params are pretty tight...

Comment: When I remove the attr_accessor line line, I get NoMethodError in Incomes#new.   but it references the form...undefined method `first_name' for #<Income id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: could you add your routes.rb file content (config folder) to your question above. I just want to check that your routes are ok. Secondly, check from your database are Incomes saved. Using console type: rails dbconsole  (Enter) after that type: select * from Incomes; (Enter) exit console by typing: .exit (Enter remember the dot .exit) If there are lines from your dbase then it's saving data

Comment: @jyrkim thanks.  db read out:   32|2015-02-18 20:50:13.022500|2015-02-18 20:50:13.022500   and a lot more where that came from.  routes in a few seconds

Comment: good that data is saved. + try in your controller before redirecting by printing out a message to your log file (it's also displayed on server console) the following to show the content of your @income object: logger.info "create income #{@income}"

Comment: also in your view add <%= debug @income %> as the first line in the view. More info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Thanks I think your routes are okay :-)

Comment: will get back to you asap...!

Comment: Thanks RailsOuter and jyrkim.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RailsOuter and @jyrkim for your help.  I found that the problem was indeed with my model file, and migration file.

I needed to remove the line attr_accessor from my model.  I have since discovered that I must have modified my migration file to add columns, instead of generating a new migration.  Now I have generated the new migration with the data columns, my data is showing!

Thanks again, very appreciative of  your input to help out a newbie!